# Scrapy With Splash Only Scrapes 1 Page

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape multiple URLs, but for some reason only results for 1 site show. In every case it is the last URL in start_urls that is shown.

I believe I have the problem narrowed down to my parse function.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
class HeatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "heat"

start_urls = ['https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=new+york&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2', 'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=dallas&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
            endpoint='render.html',
            args={'wait': 8},
        )

def parse(self, response):
    for metric in response.css('.matrix-data'):
        yield {
            'City': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
            'Metric Data Title': metric.css('.title::text').extract_first(),
            'Metric Data Price': metric.css('.price::text').extract_first(),
        }
```

EDIT:

I have altered my code to help debug. After running this code, my csv looks like this: [csv results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAiz1.png) 
There is a row for every url, as there should be, but only one row is filled out with information.

```
class HeatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "heat"

start_urls = ['https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=new+york&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2', 'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=dallas&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
            endpoint='render.html',
            args={'wait': 8},
        )


def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'City': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
        'Metric Data Title': response.css('.matrix-data .title::text').extract(),
        'Metric Data Price': response.css('.matrix-data .price::text').extract(),
        'url': response.url,
    }
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the full output http://pastebin.com/cLM3T05P
On line 46 you can see the empty cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was *adding the [delay](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY) between the requests*:

> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before
>   downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used
>   to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
```

Tested it on the 4 urls and got the results for all of them:

```
start_urls = [
    'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=new+york&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2',
    'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=dallas&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2',
    'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=washington&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2',
    'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=philadelphia&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2',
]
```

Comment: That was it!! Thank you so much Alex!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)

> **start_requests()**
>
> This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl for this spider.
>
> This is the method called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for scraping when no particular URLs are specified. If particular URLs are specified, the make_requests_from_url() is used instead to create the Requests. This method is also called only once from Scrapy, so it’s safe to implement it as a generator.

You either specify the urls inside the `start_requests()` or override [`make_requests_from_url(url)`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.make_requests_from_url) to make the requests from the `start_urls`.

Example 1

```
start_urls = []
def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=new+york&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2', 'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=dallas&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2']
    for url in urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
        endpoint='render.html',
        args={'wait': 8},
        dont_filter=True
        )
```

Example 2

```
start_urls = ['https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=new+york&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2', 'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=dallas&startDate=11/15/2016&endDate=11/16/2016&regionId=&adults=2']
def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
        endpoint='render.html',
        args={'wait': 8},
        dont_filter=True
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Example 1 produced the same result as the method I tried originally. I could not get example 2 to work. I received an "unexpected indentation error"

Comment: The duplicate error is being produced because the uniqueness of the url is being evaluated until the character `#` is found. so basically `https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?` == `https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?` To solve this just add `dont_filter=True` in the request call.

Comment: The indentation error you should be able to solve that yourself

Comment: Thank you again! With dont_filter=True, I get the same results. I have used Example 1 exactly, and the csv is identical to the one I posted in an edit above

Comment: Also, because both urls appear correctly in the csv, I think they are being read correctly.

Comment: Can you show scrapy's output from start to finish? you can put it in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I think you are on to something about the uniqueness of the urls. I added a url from a different domain to the list and it rendered and scraped both urls successfully then. Do I need to add more code to use dont_filter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) is configured properly?

Scrapy default dupefilter doesn't take URL fragments in account (i.e. part of URL after #) because this part is not sent to the server as a part of HTTP request. But fragment is important if you render a page in a browser.

scrapy-splash provides a custom dupefilter which takes fragment in account; to enable it set `DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'`. If you don't use this dupefilter both requests will have the same fingerprint (they are the same if fragment is removed), so the second request will be filtered out.

Try checking that all other settings are also correct (see https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#configuration).

Comment: I do have the dupefilter enabled in settings.py. Also, in my csv both url's are displayed correctly. I think that is a sign that both url's are unique and that the whole url is being read.

Comment: I misunderstood 'In every case it is the last URL in start_urls that is shown.' in question description then.

Comment: Oh gotcha! After the edit I made, if I put 4 urls in the array I will get 3 mostly blank rows and only 1 row, the last url in the array, will be populated correctly